# Ruby: how to modify part of a string using aliasing

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a document and I'm storing it as a single string. I need to extract certain chunks of text from the document and within those chunks (but never outside of them!) modify lines matched by another regexp. To be specific, my goal is to replace empty lines within chunks matched by `E_DISCLAIMER` with some arbitrary string. Is it possible to obtain a reference to a substring so that I can apply `String#gsub` only to that range within a string?

This is what I've been able to come up so far:

```
def disambiguate_blanks(text)
    # 1. scan for blocks between separators
    # 2. match blocks against document to get starting index
    # 3. extract matched blocks using start + length
    # 4. tag blank lines in blocks by appending a special string
    matchdata = text.scan(E_DISCLAIMER)
    blocks = matchdata.map(&:join).map(&:gsub(/^[=_*]+|[=_*]+$/, ""))
    matched_blocks = blocks.reduce(Hash.new) { |h, b| 
        h[b] = text.index(b)
        h
    }
    extracted_blocks = []
    matched_blocks.each { |block, start| 
        eb = text[start..start + block.size]
        extracted_blocks << eb
    }
    extracted_blocks.each { |eb|
        eb.gsub!(/(^)(\n)/, '\1::EMPTY::\2') 
    }
    return text
end
```

The idea is to have the changes applied in the last block also apply to `text`. Currently it is not the case, as `String#[]` returns a new string.

Comment: You may use something like `text = text.gsub(/pattern1/) { |m| m.gsub(/pattern2/, 'replacement') } `

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `&:gsub(/^[=_*]+|[=_*]+$/, "")` is not a valid ruby and should raise an exception.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It seems to work, thanks! Will do some testing now to make sure.

Comment: @mudasobwa correct. I had that line split into two separate mappings in IRB, but tried to make the transcribed method as short as possible. Thanks!